# How can I uninstall Microsoft Office 2010?

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I installed Microsoft Office 2010 using PlayOnLinux. Later, I removed Office through PlayOnLinux, and then removed PlayOnLinux through the software center. However, if I search in the dash, all the office programs show up in the results.

Removing PlayOnLinux through the software center did not remove the playonlinux folders in home, so I deleted those myself. That didn't fix the problem. Deleting the hidden wine folders in home also did not fix it.

Where are the Office programs installed, and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

If the programs are not working when you try to launch them, it might just be their shortcuts which remain in the dash.

You can use the program "[Alacarte](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/alacarte)" also known as "Main Menu" to edit applications appearing in the dash.

Comment: You're correct that the programs don't work when I try to launch them. The dash closes when I click on the shortcut, but the program doesn't launch (as expected, since I uninstalled/deleted them).

However, they still show up in the dash even after unchecking them in Main Menu (and rebooting).

Thanks for your help.